# Short story about experiment with two balls pendulum that travels in time

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

Can't find the source of a short story about an experiment scientist are making with two balls traveling in opposite direction in time. At the end of the experiment nothing seems to happen. But actually the world was totally changed as the scientists are no more humans with legs and hands.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Short story ID: Bouncing-Ball Time Travel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95186/short-story-id-bouncing-ball-time-travel)

Comment: @InventPalooza we don't close Story-IDs unless both are accepted. See [this meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7067/98028)

Answer (score 10):

William Tenn, [Brooklyn Project](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41581).

Also an accepted answer to this old question:

- [Short story ID: Bouncing-Ball Time Travel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95186/short-story-id-bouncing-ball-time-travel/95188#95188)

The answer to the older question is extremely well done, please see it for details.

Comment: And if this is the story, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons. If it's not present, the odds are that you accidentally created a new account.

Comment: An just in case, if you did create two accounts, you can merge them by following [these instructions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).