# Sci-fi novella about a group of people and a giant pendulum that swung, slowly coming to a halt

Tags: story-identification, novel, parallel-universe

I am trying to figure out a sci-fi novella I read maybe 30 years ago. It was about a group of people and a giant pendulum that swung from side to side, but slowly coming to a halt. For every swing, it created a new reality from one of the people (all pretty horrible), until it finally stopped at something normal (or did it ?).

I also remember that one character had hi-fi as a hobby and was suddenly very successful with this in the "final, normal" reality, which kind of resonates with me.

Searched on find books and sci-fi forums unsuccessfully.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this, and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: Don't know, maybe 30 years ago. Do not remember the cover

Comment: We had a prior question here involving a device that was making changes in the past at an increasing rate with the people in the hall unaware of the changes, but we the readers noticing. I vaguely remember a "ping pong" or "yo-yo" description.

Comment: Ah, https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95186/short-story-id-bouncing-ball-time-travel although now I don't think it matches very well with the details.

Comment: There is a rather hare brained story by Robert Silverberg called [Cronos](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/310650.Cronos) where the time machine is a giant pendulum and on each swing it creates a new reality because it has changed the past. But it doesn't seem a close match to your description.

Comment: SOLVED: Philip K Dick: Eye in the sky.
After an accident at the Belmont Bevatron, eight people are forced into several different alternate universes. These ersatz universes are later revealed to be solipsistic manifestations of each individual's innermost fears and prejudices, bringing the story in line with Dick's penchant for subjective realities. As well as his future discussions of theology and fears about McCarthy-era authoritarianism, the novel skewers several human foibles.

Comment: add your own answer and accept it in 8 hours :)

Comment: ^_^ Well... 46 hours. Self-answers are allowed 48 hours after the question was asked.

Comment: So, no giant pendulum involved then

Comment: Only indirectly