# Short story about a press conference dealing with something space or alien-related

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read a short story in an anthology, probably 30 years ago.  I'm guessing it was written sometime between the 1950s - 1970s, but am not sure.

It was about a press conference given by a government official, dealing with something space or alien-related.  The press conference starts out normally, with very credulous media representatives eating up the government information without asking questions.  As the press conference proceeds, the nature and physical makeup of the speaker and the media begin to change.  These changes prove the point of the story, which really is more about the behavior of the media than about aliens.

Comment: This sounds like Tenn's Brooklyn Project https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95186/short-story-id-bouncing-ball-time-travel?noredirect=1&lq=1 - the press conference is about time travel and in spite of reassuring talk from the speaker, everything is altering drastically during the conference

Comment: Is it _about_ the press conference,  or did it just _contain_ a press conference?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the SFF stack exchange :-) If the story is [The Brooklyn Project](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95186/short-story-id-bouncing-ball-time-travel) please let us know and we'll mark this as a duplicate. If the story is _not_ The Brooklyn Project could you edit you answer to say what the difference are? Thanks :-)

Comment: Thank you - this is the one I was looking for!!  Thanks so much!  To Spencer: It takes place during a press conference.